# ObjectMapper - add new value to yaml file

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, objectmapper, filebeat

Below is my yaml file. Requirement is to add new line "2.log" under "paths". Now i am reading yaml file as `Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>>`.

My code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
Map<String, List<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> obj = mapper
                        .readValue(new File("filebeat.yml"), Map.class);

obj.get("filebeat.prospectors").get(0).get("paths");
 // syso is : paths: [1.log]
```

Now i need to add new element for "paths".

Original YAML File:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: "log"
  paths: 
    - "1.log"
  fields:
    log_type: "log1"
output.logstash:
  hosts:
  - "127.0.0.1:5044"
```

Required YAML File:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: "log"
  paths: 
    - "1.log"
    - "2.log"
  fields:
    log_type: "log1"
output.logstash:
  hosts:
  - "127.0.0.1:5044"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the YAML in the question doesn't correspond to the data structure. For example `input_type` is correctly a list element but `output.logstash` is a key for a map entry, that conflicts with a structure like `Map<String, List<`. Since that's an easy mistake to make I'd recommend parsing into a tree and modifying. This is cleaner and works as desired:

```
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(new File("filebeat.yml"));
((ArrayNode) tree.get("filebeat.prospectors").get(0).get("paths")).add("2.log");
System.out.println(tree.get("filebeat.prospectors").get(0).get("paths"));
```

Docs for [ArrayNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html) and [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html). `JsonNode` is immutable and you need to cast to `ObjectNode` or if appropriate `ArrayNode` to modify or add elements. `readTree` parses documents into a special tree data structure that can represent any valid JSON, YAML, XML without requiring a Java class with a structure that matches the document. More details [here](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/08/entry_460.html) and [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model)

Comment: Worked. Thankyou. Exactly this is what i want. I am new to YAML ObjectMapper. Can you please explain how this got work and whats difference with mapper.readTree() and mapper.readValue()